# Edit Drupal Search Bar Block in DKAN

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, dkan

I'm attempting to put a search block into my Drupal 7 theme. I have included the following into the theme:

```
<?php
        $block = block_load('dkan_sitewide', 'dkan_sitewide_search_bar');
        if($block):
            $search = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
            print render($search);
        endif;
    ?>
```

The above code was taken from the [Nuboot Radix](https://github.com/NuCivic/dkan/tree/7.x-1.x/themes/nuboot_radix) theme.

This is what I see:

[image]

How do change the search bar? I want to:

- Remove the label
- Move the submit button onto the same line as the
  search bar
- Stop the bar going full width
- Change the button text
- Change the text inside the search bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in `/profiles/dkan/modules/dkan/dkan_sitewide/dkan_sitewide.blocks.inc` called `dkan_sitewide_dataset_search_form`:

```
function dkan_sitewide_dataset_search_form($form, $form_state) {
    $form['search'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#attributes' => array(
          'placeholder' => t('Search'),
      ),
      '#size' => 50,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Search'),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Editing the values in this array gives you some (very limited) control over the styling of the global search bar.

Keep in mind that editing this file directly is a bad idea, since it will be **overwritten** with the default contents **every time you update DKAN**. Unfortunately I am unable to find any other workout at the moment.